# Why does this recursive function count down as well as up?

Tags: javascript, recursion

It's counter-intuitive why this recursive function counts down as well as up. Can anyone explain it?

```
function counter(value, limit) {
    if (value === limit) {
        console.log(value);
    } else {
        console.log('going up:', value); // on the way down / going deeper (increment)
        counter(value + 1, limit);
        console.log('going down:', value); // on the way up / coming up from the depths (decrement)
    }
}
counter(0, 3);
```

### Addendum

I notice when I add a `setTimeOut()`, it outputs the pre- and post-values together instead of one above and one below.

```
going up: 0
going down: 0
2022-03-07T14:33:38.701Z
going up: 1
going down: 1
2022-03-07T14:33:39.213Z
going up: 2
going down: 2
2022-03-07T14:33:39.726Z
3
```

Comment: The first time the line `console.log('going down:', value)` is executed is when all the recursive calls are done. That is when the recursive call does't enter to the `else`, all the previously called functions are returning the execution to the line after they were called.

Comment: Why is it counterintuitive? What do you think should happen when the function is called? What does the debugger reveal?

Comment: Ok, but where do the numbers counting down come from? I guess I'm hung up on looking for a `counter(value -1)` and don't see it.

Comment: Uhm what are u trying to achieve? its going down too cause there is no return statement when u recursively call counter. So after all the recursion, the going down gets printed. Its not actually going down, the last console log is just printing the value . Every iteration is holding the value in the closure.

Comment: But when it gets into `if (value === limit) {` and prints out `3` then it should drop through and be finished, right, and so not start counting back down, right?

Comment: @EdwardTanguay _“then it should drop through and be finished”_ — What is “it”; what should be finished? The functions are still not done and the call stack is not empty when `if (value === limit){ console.log(value); }` is reached. Why do you think something special should happen at this point?

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

What if we started with this version instead?

```js
function counter(value, limit) {
    if (value === limit) {
        console.log(value);
    } else {
        console.log('going up:', value);
        console .log ('*** Do some more stuff ***');
        console.log('going down:', value);
    }
}
counter(0, 3);
```

Then we would get this output:

```
going up: 0
*** Do some more stuff ***
going down: 0
```

Now let's replace that do-more-stuff with the result of calling `counter (value + 1, limit)`, which is `counter (1, 3)`, whose result would be:

```
going up: 1
*** Do some more stuff ***
going down: 1
```

Substituting that in, we get:

```
going up: 0
going up: 1
*** Do some more stuff ***
going down: 1
going down: 0
```

doing another level, we would call counter (2, 3)  to get

```js
going up: 2
*** Do some more stuff ***
going down: 2
```

and substituting that in to the above, we get

```
going up: 0
going up: 1
going up: 2
*** Do some more stuff ***
going down: 2
going down: 1
going down: 0
```

But now we call `counter (3, 3)`, and the result is that we just log the value:

```
3
```

Substituting that in, we get

```
going up: 0
going up: 1
going up: 2
3
going down: 2
going down: 1
going down: 0
```

Of course at runtime there are no such actual substitutions.  But we can think of the recursive call as something that gets stuck between "going up" and "going down", and any output from it will be placed between those two.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense with the console.log continually inserting values into the middle of the console.log outputs, but can you explain why a setTimeOut (see above) breaks this pattern?

Comment: While that should probably be a separate question, it's simple enough.  That's what `setTimeout` is for: to schedule an action to happen later.  I'm assuming you wrapped it around the recursive call.  So now, instead of synchronously making the recursive call, you've scheduled it to happen later, and the code merrily proceeds to the going-down line.  When the function ends, the system will check if there's anything scheduled, and run your recursive call when the time is right.